# set null to mongo required field before save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I guys How can I set null to mongo db required field to null before mongoose save();

schema

```
    a = new Schema({ 
      conn : {type: Object, required: true}
    })

    a.findOne(findQuery, (err, b) => {
      if(err)
        console.log(error);
      if(!b)
        console.log(errMessage);
       b.conn = null;
       b.save((err) => {
       if(err)
        console.log(err)
       -----something else----
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `default:{}` in your schema , so if there is no value passed , it will take default empty object while saving the document .

your schema should be :

```
 a = new Schema({ 
      conn : {type: Object, required: true , default:{}}
    });
```

while checking your records , you can check the length of your conn object , if object length is 0 , means there are no key-value pair exists in your db .

```
if(Object.keys(conn).length==0){
  // conn object is empty , set new key 
   conn.your_key=your_value;
  // save the document
}else{
  // conn object is not empty 
}
```

Comment: but I want to update that field with null, just call empty save function ?

Comment: as conn is type of Object , you can use empty object {} while saving .

Comment: the problem is I should check with the null, null field is required for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible but you should not specify `null` value you should just omit a field, in other words the field should be not specified in MongoDB document. The solution is, you can just add `sparse` indexing.
I don’t know if it works with `required` tag but it works with `unique` field for sure you can refer to [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

```
 a = new Schema({
  conn : {
     type: Object, 
     unique: true, 
     sparse: true
  }
```

});

Comment: Frankly speaking, the main functionality of ՝required՝ parameter is to not allow ՝null՝ value

Comment: generally I know the purpose of that, but one question when I am trying to insert with findOneAndUpdate it sets null to the required field. A little strange do you think so ? ut in generall thanks :)